# How to Implement Automatic Certificate Rotation in WIF 4.5

Tags: c#, web-config, wif

I have set-up IMS with WIF 4.5 on an MVC website. Every couple months the administrators are changing the IMS token signing certificate. They mentioned that I should be able to enable automatic certificate rotation in order to not have to update my thumbprint every time the cert is changed, but I cannot seem to figure out how that is done. Below is a sample of code from my current configuration in the web.config.

```
<system.identityModel xdt:Transform="Replace">
<identityConfiguration>
  <audienceUris>
    <add value="http://tools.mycompany.com/myapp/" />
  </audienceUris>
  <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
    <authority name="https://ims.mycompany.com/">
      <keys>
        <!-- Expires on 10/23/2017 -->
        <add thumbprint="************" />
        <!-- Begins working on 10/16/2017 -->
        <add thumbprint="************" />
      </keys>
      <validIssuers>
        <add name="https://ims.mycompany.com/" />
      </validIssuers>
    </authority>
  </issuerNameRegistry>
  <!--certificationValidationMode set to "None" by the the Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio. For development purposes.-->
  <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
  <securityTokenHandlers>
    <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </securityTokenHandlers>
</identityConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a full description of this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover).

e.g. if you use the older VS versions, you could use:

```
protected void Application_Start() { AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); ... RefreshValidationSettings(); }
```